# Want to return <title> tag but return<title> bad request <.title> Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I have a program that return the  from a list of URLs.

Some of them return Bad Request when they're being put together in a list

For example i load two URL to the into the text file:

```
http://www.scientific.net/MSF
http://www.scientific.net/JMNM
```

it return:

```
<title>Bad Request</title>
<title>Journal of Metastable and Nanocrystalline Materials</title>
```

The code works fine if I only have the first URL in the list. How do I make it retrieve both title instead of  bad request?

My code:

```
url_list= []

f = open('test.txt','r') #text file with url 
for line in f:
    url_list.append(line)

for link in url_list:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser") 
        title = soup.title
        title.string = title.get_text(strip = True)
        print(str(title))

    except:
        print("No Title Found ")
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is arising from reading from the text file. In the `for link in url_list` loop, your first value for `link` will be `http://www.scientific.net/MSF\n` - the `\n` in the end is leading to a `Bad Request` error. Strip the `\n` from lines as you read them, and your code will work. It seems your last line does not have a `\n`, so simply using `url_list.append(line[:-1])` will fail for the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser") 
    #title = soup.title
    titles = soup.find_all('title')
    for title in titles:
        title.string = title.get_text(strip = True)
        print(str(title))
```

`.` is shortcut for `.find()`, it will return the first match, you should use `find_all()` to return all matchs.